# Count and Sum of distinct values of the tuple pairs in python

Tags: python, pandas, data-manipulation

```
import pandas as pd
dt = {'order_id': ['A','A','B','B','B','C'], 'XY_ID': [4,5,4,5,6,4]}
print(pd.DataFrame(data=dt))
```

| order_id | XY_ID |
| --- | --- |
| A | 4 |
| A | 5 |
| B | 4 |
| B | 5 |
| B | 6 |
| C | 4 |

and i want by output like below which is group all unique
tuples of two from Col2 and count the number of Col1 associated with them

for 4,5 pairs A->4,B->4, A->5,B->5 count is 2, because there is 2 common relation via 4, 
for 5,6 pairs A->5, B->5 B->6 count is 1, because there is 1 common relation via 5

| XY_ID_Tuple_IDX1 | XY_ID_Tuple_ID2 | order count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 5 | 2 |
| 5 | 6 | 1 |
| 4 | 6 | 1 |

i tried with `df.groupby(['col1', 'col2']).size().reset_index(name='count')` and pivot_table()

Comment: i actually tried df.groupby(['col1', 'col2']).size().reset_index(name='count') but thats not right

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite get the logic of the output.

Comment: How do 5 and 6 relate? or 4 and 6?

Comment: @Scott group all unique tuples of two from Col2 and count the number of Col1 associated with them

Comment: In your sample code and data you don't have any tuples?  A dataframe is composed of columns and rows.  In your expected output where did the columns ID1 and ID2 come from?  How are they derived and how do the values in these columns relate to the first dataframe?

Comment: edited my Col name, for more clear understanding of relation

Comment: for 4,5 pairs A->4, A->5,B->4,B->5 count is 2, because there is 2 common relation via 4,
for 5,6 pairs A->5, B->5 B->6 count is 1, because there is 1 common relation via 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to join the dataframe with itself:

```
counts = (df.merge(df, on='order_id')
            .groupby(['XY_ID_x', 'XY_ID_y'])
            .count()
            .reset_index()
          )
counts.loc[counts['XY_ID_x'] < counts['XY_ID_y']]
```

`counts` content:

```
   XY_ID_x  XY_ID_y  order_id
1        4        5         2
2        4        6         1
5        5        6         1
```

Comment: .groupby(['XY_ID_x', 'XY_ID_y'])??? how? its gonna be a KeyError for 'XY_ID_x'

Comment: @ShivAA when two dataframes are merged, identical column names get postfixes like `_x` and `_y`. Before the groupby, `df` was merged with itself - thus, the result

Comment: It was missing a `reset_index` I think

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach using [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```
from itertools import combinations

s = (df.groupby('order_id')['XY_ID']
       .agg(lambda x: list(combinations(x, 2)))
       .explode()
     )

out = s.groupby(s).count()
```

output:

```
XY_ID
(4, 5)    2
(4, 6)    1
(5, 6)    1
Name: XY_ID, dtype: int64
```

Provided format:

```
# code above +

idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(out.index,
                                names=['XY_ID_Tuple_IDX1', 'XY_ID_Tuple_IDX2'])
out2 = out.to_frame('order_id').set_axis(idx).reset_index()
```

output:

```
   XY_ID_Tuple_IDX1  XY_ID_Tuple_IDX2  order_id
0                 4                 5         2
1                 4                 6         1
2                 5                 6         1
```